# Is it wise to store a list of objects as a variable in another object?

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

So lets say I have an order which lists multiple items and some attributes like their ID and prices.... My original concept involved treating these objects separately and having the items listed in each order associated via both the listed item and the order it is associated with share an attribute *Being the order_ID* if so how can i store the list of objects in a sql database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic problem.  And, it has a "right" answer.  The write answer is to have a separate table for the items in the order.  Here is an example of such a table:

```
create table OrderItems (
    OrderItemId int not null auto_increment,
    OrderId int,
    ItemId int,
    Price Money,
    CreatedBy varchar(255),
    CreatedAt timestamp
);
```

This format is a *normalized* format, meaning (in simple terms) that each separate entity gets its own table.  The `OrderItems` table itself is really just connecting orders to items, providing a way to have a list of items within an order.

If you come from a programming background, it might take some time and effort to get used to normalization in SQL databases.  Think of normalized data as a way of storing data that makes the SQL engines more efficient, because they are really good at bringing data in different tables together.